# Reverse menu order in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function, wordpress-theming

Have a very quick question, and i presume simple, but as its late in the day, i can't seem to solve it...

I have a wordpress menu floated to the right. To correct the order, i need to display the menu in reverse. I am using this function to do this, and placing it just before the menu is called in header:

```
<?php add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', create_function( '$menu', 'return array_reverse( $menu );' ) ); ?>
```

As i only want to reverse one menu, i need to put a remove_filter after the menu... and can't figure it out... or maybe the add_filter function is wrong in the first place.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Why not use the `order` argument when displaying your menu?

Comment: Fro what i read, the reverse menu order seems to be more logical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress’ plugin API offers no simple access to anonymous functions or closures.

Use a regular function as callback instead:

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'reverse_menu' );

function reverse_menu( $menu ) {
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );
    return array_reverse( $menu );
}
```

Never use `create_function()`. It is slow, hard to debug, and it doesn’t work well with opcaches.

Comment: This quickly solves the problem. Why is create_function still used?